# C# Disable partly functionality in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I have a function that creates a user, stores in the database and subscribes it to a Mailchimp list.
I have a unit test that tests this function.

Now I do want to test this function, but I dont want the 'mocked' user to be added to the mailinglist.

Is there a way to partly exclude code execution when a function is run in a unit test mode?

So for example I have this function (simplyfied)

```
public async Task<CreateUserResponse> Create(CreateUserRequest createRequest){
    
    //Save user to database
    var encryptedPassword = encryptor.EncryptPassword(createRequest.Password, salt);
    var user = new UserDomain(){
          EmailAddress = createRequest.EmailAddress,
          Password = encryptedPassword,
          Salt = salt
    }
    _dbContext.Users.Add(user);

    //Subscribe to mailing list
    var mailChimpAdapter = new MailChimpAdapter(_configuration);
    mailChimpAdapter.Subscribe(user);

    return new CreateUserResponse(user);
}
```

Now I want to run a unit test to test that function but without subscribing it.
Best I can think of is using a variable in the config file and read it out inside the function. But maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to extract an interface from MailChimpAdapter (say, IMailChimpAdapter) and then use it to mock the constructor and the subscribe method. You can use a library like Moq.

Check this for a quick [intro](https://softchris.github.io/pages/dotnet-moq.html#moq-how-it-works) :